# Building a Bio-impedance system

Tags: stm32, current-measurement, electricity

I currently have a project that has integrated sensors to monitor human health and related biomarkers, my domain is human-performance so giving athletes the tools to get better at their respective game.

I have recently begun trying to gather information regarding bioimpedance in order to implement this in my embedded project. For a prototype I am using the STM32 series ( blue pill chip ) to package a sensorframe of values ( o2, pulse, gyro & acc data, temperature ) now I really want to add bioimpedance to this device - heres what I think I know so far anyways

- We need to emit an electric current over a multi-channel ( I want to calculate bone density, muscle mass, fat mass)
- We need an emitter and a receiver
- there needs to be two connected components by a wire that connect the two devices that complete the circuit

My questions are this, what frequency do I need to use to calculate my targets?

Comment: shock: a sudden upsetting or surprising event or experience.  Not sure you'll have many takers on your device...other than a few masochists.

Comment: Welcome to EE-SE. It may be hard to get some traction here with that question. What is your background and experience with electronics?

Comment: my background is mostly software development with some exposure to hardware, but I have built embedded projects using various languages and understand the various communication interfaces, my weak area is EE and designing circuits at this point which is why I reached out here; although I understand high-level bioimpedance I do not know how to build the circuit with a wholistic understanding. @P2000

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, they use at least 2 frequencies with a current source and measure the voltage as impedance.  The current is only 1~10uA and f1=10k~100kHz f2=1~10MHz.

You can multiplex the signals with analog Mux.

https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article-pdf/64/3/388S/24035357/388s.pdf